# Not sure how to do this regex

Tags: php, regex, markdown

After asking the question below and thinking on it, I believe this regex is all I need. Not sure how to do it.

`![anycharacter](anycharacter)` to `[anycharacter](anycharacter)`

-Original title and message-

PHP Markdown Extra - Not allowing images

Right now I just have css set to hide images in the area where markdown is allowed. I would like to make it so that if markdown image syntax is used, images won't show. I would actually prefer it to just be turned into a link, but simply disallowing it would be fine. I guess a regex to check for `![text](imagelink)` would work, but I am not versed enough in regex to do it or to knw whether that would be the best option or not.

-edit- right now I am doing a preg_replace of  `preg_replace('/!\[/', "[", $text );` but I still don't think that is the best solution as it will remove the ! even at times there might be another reason ![ comes up. I guess I just need to know how to do replace `![anycharacter](anycharacter)` with `[anycharacter](anycharacter)`

Comment: What is your question? How do you encode images?

Comment: @mightyuhu Do you not know what PHP Markdown is? I said exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not my code its from http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/1.5.1.3/wp-content/plugins/markdown.php but you could use it to prepass your input within your
_DoImages_reference_callback($matches) and _DoImages_inline_callback($matches) functions,
this however is just a gist.

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('{
    (               # wrap whole match in $1
      !\[
        (.*?)       # alt text = $2
      \]

      [ ]?              # one optional space
      (?:\n[ ]*)?       # one optional newline followed by spaces

      \[
        (.*?)       # id = $3
      \]

    )
    }xs', 
    '_DoImages_reference_callback', $text);

#
# Next, handle inline images:  ![alt text](url "optional title")
# Don't forget: encode * and _

$text = preg_replace_callback("{
    (               # wrap whole match in $1
      !\\[
        (.*?)       # alt text = $2
      \\]
      \\(           # literal paren
        [ \\t]*
        <?(\S+?)>?  # src url = $3
        [ \\t]*
        (           # $4
          (['\"])   # quote char = $5
          (.*?)     # title = $6
          \\5       # matching quote
          [ \\t]*
        )?          # title is optional
      \\)
    )
    }xs",
    '_DoImages_inline_callback', $text);
```